# Save a javascript code as store function via Java API

Tags: mongodb-java

I want to save a javascript code as store function via Java API. The problem is that I don't know how to convert String (type 2) to code (type 13). I know that in PHP it's possible:

```
new mongo.Code("function myFunction() { return 123; }").
```

So is there any way to save stored function via Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very similar in Java:

```
final Code code = new Code("function myFunction() { return 123; }");
```